# Show "Thank you message" in same popup window in Magnific popup with gravity forms

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to keep showing "Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly." message in same Magnific popup window after form been submitted. At the moment after form been submitted window closes. Code I using:

```js
<script>
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      closeOnBgClick: false,
      fixedContentPos: true,
      closeOnContentClick: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

```css
  .white-popup {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="test-popups" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  Popup content
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id=4 title=false description=false]'); ?>
</div>
<a href="#test-popups" class="open-popup-link">Contact Us</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the "ajax" parameter, only the form markup will be refreshed rather than the whole page.

`[gravityform id="4" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]`

Comment: Glad to help. Also worth mentioning is the gravity_form() method which you can call directly versus processing it as a shortcode. https://docs.gravityforms.com/adding-a-form-to-the-theme-file/#function-call